# Why does some bluetooth devices only expose their MAC without name?

Tags: android, bluetooth

When i set "Show devices without names" off on developer mode i see only a few bluetooth devices around me with their names.
However when i set it on, i see a lot of bluetooth MAC address, around 50 of them, and i expected that after a few minutes they will all broadcast their names, but nothing is changing.
Even if i wait 30 minutes, my devices still don't get their names.
Any idea why some devices won't expose their names?
I have tried waiting for long periods of time, and i have poked around on forums, but nothing helpful found.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth devices can advertise using their MAC address and name but the latter is not required, thus you get devices with no names. I would assume these Bluetooth devices are not meant to be connected to by just anyone and they only advertise out of necessity.

I have personally experienced this with my own Bluetooth discovery app. I would say it's fairly normal.

Comment: Which devices don't advertise names? I am scanning with android phone

Answer (score 1):

Their count is more strange than not reporting a name. Are there indeed 50 BT devices present around you? To me this sounds alike sitting right next to a whole box of beacons.

There's not much to do about it, but one can manually assign names to them. By the question it's unclear which device you're even using, but certain vendor-specific implementations may even fail to read the names, altogether.

Comment: i use android phone, this hardly seems like a malfunction as this phenomena happens consistently with multiple android phones. I can't seem to figure out what all those MAC addresses belong to, and why they don't have name signature

Comment: @forstackoverflowizi In my tests with BLE scanner apps and 2 phones, it turned out both phones sent out nameless MACs with Device Type: UNKOWN but most likely LE. These MACs do no align with the Bluetooth MAC in Phone > Status. I think they're generated aka MAC Address Randomization. Those MACs are not visible in native Android BT scanner, only with BLE scanners. So it seems BLE is activated behind our backs when we turn on Bluetooth. I've also been testing the scenario that people emit BLE, post 2020 after medical interventions involving needles and nose sticks, and was not able to debunk.

Answer (score -3):

These bluetooth devices are being produced by old cell phones or old application on your cell phone or a smart watch or a lamb